# Mips: going back to incorrect return address

Tags: mips, mips32, mips64, smips

I have a mini bank program written that goes calls multiple functions inside the subrouting deposit, this is the subroutine

```
deposit:
    addi $sp, $sp, -8 #save space on stack
    addi $s3, $0, 1 #trigger s3
    sw $s3, 0($sp)
    sw $ra, 4($sp)
    .....
    jal AsciiConvert #convert ascii of deposited amount to integer
    beq $v0, $0, Err_ACC #if no value to be deposited was inputed print error message
    beq $t0, $0, deposit_checking #if check exists returns a 0
    beq $t0, 1, deposit_saving #if check exists returns a 1
    jal printarray
    lw $s3, 0($sp)
    lw $ra, 4($sp)      # reload $ra so we can return to caller
    addi $sp, $sp, 8   # restore $sp, freeing the allocated space
    jr $ra   
    
deposit_checking:
    ... arithmetic operations...
    jr $ra
```

the ascii convert subroutine:

```
AsciiConvert:
    ...normal arithemtics...
    j ConvertOP
ConvertOP:
    lb $s0, 0($a1)
    beq $s0, $0, endConvert #end at null terminating
    beq $s0,32,endConvert #if found a space
    addi $s0, $s0, -48 #convert to int
    mul $s2, $s1, 10 #multiply sum by 10
    add $s2, $s2, $s0 #sum = sum + previous number
    add $s1, $s2, $0 #s1 holds previous value
    addi $a1, $a1, 1 #increment adress
    add $v0, $s2, $0 #store the number in the return adress
    j ConvertOP
endConvert:
    jr $ra
```

When I go into deposit, I jal AsciiConvert and then I go into the deposit_Checking subroutine, however the return address of that deposit_Checking  returns me back to the line of jal AsciiConvert and not to the line where I called the deposit_Checking subroutine, leading to an infinite loop between Ascii convert subroutine and deposit_Checking subroutine...can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deposit_checking` looks like a subroutine, and you identify it as a subroutine in your post, but, we don't enter subroutines with `beq` instruction, you're supposed to use `jal` to call a subroutine.

In machine code, the return address, `$ra` for MIPS, is effectively a parameter to the subroutine — it tells the subroutine where to resume execution in the caller, where to return to.  There are several ways to set the `$ra` register with a meaningful return address, though of course `jal` is by far the most common way.

`beq` transfers control of the processor to the target label (when eq is true) by changing the program counter (pc) though does not provide a (new) `$ra` value.

By not setting `$ra` to a new value, its old value is retained.  Since the `$ra` register was last set by the `jal AsciiConvert`, the `jr $ra` for the other function goes back there, none the wiser that this was not the right call — as it is the caller's job to set that parameter properly.

And while some instruction sets allow calling on a condition, we wouldn't necessarily want all `beq`s to capture a return address, because then any function that used `beq` would have to concern itself with preserving `$ra`.

Let's also note that these behaviors are all visible during debugging.  `jr $ra`, for example will transfer control to whatever machine instruction is addressed by the value in the `$ra` register.  When you first enter a subroutine/function, there should be a proper return address parameter provided in `$ra` register, and by the time you get to the end of the function with its final instruction `jr $ra`, if the value in the `$ra` register's value has changed from entry, then it won't go back to where it was called from — so we'd be looking for somewhere in between that changes `$ra`, without restoring it back.